# Keras input shape error - passing the whole array not each line

Tags: arrays, input, keras, shapes

I am loading images from a csv file. The images are 300 x 300 pixels but flattened to 90000. I am getting an error for input shape. I am using tensorflow back end. I have attached an image of my csv file as well as an image of the error. It looks like its passing the whole list of arrays instead of passing each line.

"ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 380 arrays:[array([  43.,   45.,   46., ...,  161.,  152.,  146.]), array([ 211.,  222.,  224., ...,  212.,  213.,  213.]), array([ 201.,  201., "

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhHC0.jpg)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT4xh.jpg)

```
            import numpy as np
            from keras.models import Sequential
            from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
            import csv
            import cv2
            import re

            loaded_images_train = []
            loaded_labels_train = []

            loaded_images_test = []
            loaded_labels_test = []

            with open('images_train.csv') as f:
                csvReader = csv.reader(f, lineterminator = '\n')
                for row in csvReader:
                    row = np.asarray(row, dtype='float')
                    loaded_images_train.append(row)

            with open('labels_train.csv') as f:
                csvReader = csv.reader(f, lineterminator = '\n')
                for row in csvReader:
                    row = str(row)
                    row = row.strip(',')
                    loaded_labels_train.append(row)

            with open('images_test.csv') as f:
                csvReader = csv.reader(f, lineterminator = '\n')
                for row in csvReader:
                    row = np.asarray(row, dtype='float')
                    loaded_images_test.append(row)

            with open('labels_test.csv') as f:
                csvReader = csv.reader(f, lineterminator = '\n')
                for row in csvReader:
                    row = str(row)
                    row = row.strip(',')
                    loaded_labels_test.append(row)



            # load data
            x_train = loaded_images_train
            y_train = loaded_labels_train
            print("Loaded Training Data")

            x_test = loaded_images_test
            y_test = loaded_labels_test
            print("Loaded Testing Data")

            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(90000,), activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dropout(0.5))
            model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dropout(0.5))
            model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

            model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                           optimizer='rmsprop',
                           metrics=['accuracy'])
            model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                        epochs=20,
                        batch_size=128)
            #score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
            print(score)
```

Comment: Could you try `x_train = np.stack(loaded_images_train)`?

Comment: I get a new error "in stack
    raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape". Each array in the list has the same shape. I printed them out to make sure. the shape of each array in the list is (90000,) which is what I used as my input shape.

Comment: What's the value of `all(len(x) == 90000 for x in loaded_images_train)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are converting each line with `asarray` and then feeding keras with a `list` of arrays is not working.

I've tested your code with a sightly different approach and it did run flawlessly for me with the csv you provided in the comments (changing `input_size` to 400).

Read all lines from the file to `loaded_images_train`. It will be a list of lists:

```
input_size = 90000

with open('images_train.csv') as f:
    csvReader = csv.reader(f, lineterminator = '\n')
    for row in csvReader:
        assert len(row) == input_size
        loaded_images_train.append(row)
```

I've included the assertion following your feedback to my comment.
You can also `assert len(row) == output_size` for the labels.

On the other hand, if you are pretty sure about the sizes of the rows, you can substitute the loop by a simple:

```
loaded_images_train = list(csvReader)
```

Whichever you choose, do the same to test images.

Then do the conversion to `numpy.ndarray` when declaring `x_train`:

```
x_train = np.asarray(loaded_images_train, dtype=float)  # you don't really need the quotes here
```

Finally, printing the shape of the loaded data can help you know that everything is ok. For example:

```
print("Loaded Training Data", x_train.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you met the problem is the type of your dataset is `list`, but the acceptable type for Keras model is only `numpy array`.

You need to convert the lists to `numpy array` with `np.asarray(loaded_images_train)` and make sure the shape of the data is `(n,90000)`.

Comment: The loaded_images_train array contains 380 images. Each image is a flattened to a one dimensional array. If I used the np.asarray(loaded_images_train)) it will return a shape of (380,1).

Comment: It's a little strange, can you supply a link to download the csv file to help me figure out it?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cx6su0cx7nv2h56/labels_train.csv?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kz5woc159hmug46/images_train.csv?dl=0
http://vonderasche.blogspot.nl/2017/11/images-to-csv-files.html

I created the csv file. I attached a link to the images and labels. I also put a link of the code I wrote to create the files.

Comment: sorry, I can't open the link to csv file.

Comment: I uploaded a smaller version of the file. I appreciate the time your taking to help me. I also made the image smaller.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mgg8c0hw6ld47p/images.csv?dl=0